# How to detect the length of a string? (batch)

Tags: string, batch-file, string-length

I'm trying to make a batch file to solve a puzzle. At my current moment I need a way to detect the length of a string. I don't really know where to start and did not find any related articles on a title search.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=string+length+batch

Comment: @Magoo Unfortunately my searches were poor, Apparrently...

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 set "line=this is my string"

 for /l %%a in (0,1,8191) do (
    Set "each=!line:~%%a,1!"
    if not defined each echo length: %%a & endlocal & set length=%%a & goto :eof
 )
```

If you want to test the length of the string excluding special characters or whitespace you need to remove whitespace and escape special characters before setting `each`